# Package version in Linux (Centos)?

Tags: centos, package, version, rpm

I need to retrieve the package versions for all packages installed on my Linux (Centos) host. rpm -qa gives me list of all installed packages.
I understand that rpm -qi "package name" gives me package information. I tried doing a grep for package version from there and pick the version for display - but this creates a problem for some packages as some text gets appended for some of the packages along with the version. Below is my code line:-
rpm -qi "package name"| grep -w Version | awk '{print $3}'

Is there any other way to get the package version - probably from package name itself? We need a report with package names in one column and versions in second column. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `rpm -qa --qf '%{name}\t%{version}\n'`? Optionally with `| column -t` on the end?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am also writing timestamp and the ip address of the host in first two columns. Below is my actual code:- for i in $(rpm -qa); do echo $tdydate ","  $(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}') "," $i "," $(rpm -qi $i| grep -w Version | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/ .*//') >> $HOME/MyLog/installed_packages.csv; done

Comment: Would you be able to help here... In the fourth column, I need the version. The output is actually a CSV file.

Comment: `rt=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}'); rpm -qa --qf "$tdydate,$rt,%{name},%{version}\n"` or something like that.

Comment: That worked clean. Thanks a lot mate for quick revert, much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can tell rpm how to construct its output using the `--qf` flag. It takes a format string as an argument.

So something like the following should get you what you want.

```
rt=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}')
rpm -qa --qf "$tdydate,$rt,%{name},%{version}\n"
```